# Prove that $f(r)=\mu(A \cap B(0,r))$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Let $ A\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ measurable, and $f:\mathbb{R^+}\to \mathbb{R}, f(r)=\mu(A \cap B(0,r))$. (Lebesgue's measure)

I want to show that $f$ is continuous.

First, if $c=\mu(B(0,1))\to r^dc=\mu(B(0,r))$.

Let $\epsilon>0$.

Now, $|\mu(A\cap B(0,r))- \mu(A\cap B(0,r_0))|=\mu(A\cap (B(0,r)\triangle B(0,r_0)))\leq$ $ \mu (B(0,r)\triangle B(0,r_0))=$ $|r^d-r_0^d|c\leq$ $ |r-r_0|dMc$
 for $M$ sufficiently greater. Put $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{dMc}$ and we finish.

My questions are, is my solution right? Is there another more "visual" solution (less technical) without using theorems?
Thanks!

Comment: By $\triangle$ you mean intersection?

Comment: @iiivooo looks like symmetric difference of sets

Comment: Exactly, symmetric difference

Comment: I think your solution is the the most straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Choose some $R>0$ and suppose $r^* < R$.

If $r<R$, then $f(r) = \int 1_A 1_{B(0,r)}$ and $|1_A(x) 1_{B(0,r)}(x)| \le 1_{B(0,R)}(x)$ for all 
$x$ and all $r <R$, and $1_{B(0,R)}(x)$ is integrable.

We have $\lim_{r \to r^*} 1_A(x) 1_{B(0,r)}(x) = 1_A(x) 1_{B(0,r^*)}(x)$ for ae. $x$ (in particular, for $x$ such that $\|x\| \neq r^*$), and
so using the dominated convergence theorem we have $f(r) \to f(r^*)$.

Answer (score 0):

For every  $r>0$, for every $c>0$ there exists $a$ such that if $\mid r'-r\mid <a$ implies that $\mu (B(0,r')-B(0,r))=\mid \mu(B(0,r)-\mu(B(0,r')\mid<c$ if $r'>r$ or $\mu(B(0,r)-\mu(B(0,r'))=\mid \mu(B(0,r)-\mu(B(0,r'))<c$  if $r>r'$.

If $r>r'$, $\mid \mu(A\cap B(0,r)-\mu(A\cap B(0,r'))\mid =\mu (A\cap (B(0,r)-B(0,r'))\leq \mu(B(0,r)-B(0,r'))<c$.

The situation $r<r'$ is similar.

Comment: The existence of this a is the problem... You can't suppose that exist...

Comment: really why, the function $r\rightarrow vol B(0,r)$ is continuous

Comment: OK, if you assume this, your solution is right. My idea was solve it without theory or previous propositions :)

Comment: Eventually, you use that too, otherwise where comes $r^d$? saying that $r\rightarrow r^d$ is continuous is not really using a theory according to me.